# A general-use For-comprehensible Loan Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, scala

I use Scala's loan pattern in order to ensure and automate the resource aquisition and release after its use. When multiple resources have to be acquired at once, however, the function calls must be nested, impairing readability.

[Scala ARM](http://jsuereth.com/scala-arm/) supports for-comprehension to avoid the nesting. However, in order to have Scala ARM manage resources, the managed class must extend scala.resource.Resource or simply AutoCloseable, which requires a definiton of `close()` method.

I'd like to avoid defining `close()` methods because it separates aquisition and release into different methods but I believe such operations are so tightly coupled that keeping them close will enhance the maintainability.

My idea is to restrict resource access to only via certain loaner-functions, while supporting for-comprehension to keep readability.

So, I wrote a trait `ForComprehensible`:

```
/**
 * @tparam A The type of the loaned object.
 */
trait ForComprehensible[+A] {
  /**
   * The loaner-function. Subclasses must define this.
   *
   * @tparam B The result type of the callback
   * @param  f The callback
   * @return The result value of the callback
   */
  def apply[B](f: A => B) : B

  def map[B](f: A => B)     : B    = apply(f)
  def flatMap[B](f: A => B) : B    = apply(f)
  def foreach[B](f: A => B) : Unit = { apply(f); () }

  // The methods filter and withFilter are omitted on purpose because they don't make sense.
}
```

Since `ForComprehensible` defines the `apply` method, client code can use one much like an ordinary loaner-function. Here is a simple example program which copies a content of a file into another:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.OutputStream
import scala.annotation.tailrec

// Opens a FileInputStream and loans it to the callback. After that, closes the stream.
def withInputStream(infilename: String) = new ForComprehensible[FileInputStream] {
  override def apply[B](f: FileInputStream => B) = {
    val res = new FileInputStream(infilename)
    try {
      f(res)
    } finally {
      res.close()
    }
  }
}

// Opens a FileOutputStream and loans it to the callback. After that, closes the stream.
def withOutputStream(outfilename: String) = new ForComprehensible[FileOutputStream] {
  override def apply[B](f: FileOutputStream => B) = {
    val res = new FileOutputStream(outfilename)
    try {
      f(res)
    } finally {
      res.close()
    }
  }
}

// Pipes all the content of the input stream into the output stream.
@tailrec def pipe(is: InputStream, os: OutputStream) : Unit = {
  val bytes = new Array[Byte](1024)
  val n = is.read(bytes)
  if (n >= 0) {
    os.write(bytes, 0, n)
    pipe(is, os)
  }
}

// The following are equivalent. Both automatically close streams.
// Without for-comprehension:
withInputStream("input.txt"){ is =>
  withOutputStream("output.txt"){ os =>
    pipe(is, os)
  }
}

// With for-comprehension:
for {
  is <- withInputStream("input.txt")
  os <- withOutputStream("output.txt")
} {
  pipe(is, os)
}
```

It works and looks nice. Before writing this, I googled for "scala loan pattern for-comprehension" and found nothing looking relevant. I think this trait is quite straight-forward and I doubt no one ever come up with something like this.

So I've got skeptical; is there any problem with this?

Comment: "bracket" is another name for this: https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/wiki/0.8#preemption-changes

Answer (score 2):

As long as you restrict yourself to simple uses, I think it's ok. When you try complex tricks, however, the lack of definition of the `filter` (or `withFilter`) method leads to certain inconveniences. Here are examples:

### Binding to a tuple

```
for {
  // opens two files at once and returns a tuple of Input/OutputStreams
  (is, os) <- withIOStream("input.txt", "output.txt") // (doesn't work)
} { ... }
```

This doesn't work because assigning to a tuple (or more generally, a pattern) involves a call to `filter`. If you want to use pattern matching, bind it to a variable first, and then match it against a tuple in the for expression.

### Guards

```
for {
  // handle only if the file is not empty
  is <- withInputStream("input.txt") if is.available() > 0 // (doesn't work)
} { ... }
```

This doesn't work because an "if" guard is translated to a call to `filter`. Since the guard (usually) depends on the loaned object (in this example, `is`), such conditionals must be put into the body of the for expression.

---

The trait is still "safe" because both of the above are catched at compilation time. However, experienced Scala programmers may find it cumbersome when they write up a complex generator and then get errors.

Can we get them work? A naïve approach is to define `filter` and `withFilter` like:

```
// unsafe, incorrect for certain uses
trait ForComprehensible[+A] {
  ...

  // ignore the filtering and just return itself
  def filter(f: A => Boolean): ForComprehensible[A] = this
  // not essential here, just to suppress compiler warnings
  def withFilter(f: A => Boolean) = filter(f)
}
```

this enables binding to a tuple (for some reason I don't fully understand), but causes guards to be silently ignored (i.e. assumes true). This makes `ForComprehensible` an unsafe construct.

<strike>If we are to implement `filter` (and `withFilter`) properly, we have to open a `FileInputStream` (in our example) in **the `filter` method**. It means the stream must be opened twice (in `filter` and `apply`), or we open it once in `filter` and then keep it open using some magic until the callback of `apply` returns. The former is simply unacceptable, and the latter would make the implementation of the trait too complicated.</strike>

**EDIT:** after some more experiments, I found out that a guard on `ForComprehensible` is not an implementation problem but rather a *semantic* problem.

Consider:

```
for {
  is <- withInputStream("input.txt") if is.available() > 0
} yield { ... }
```

note the `yield`. What this whole expression has to return if the guard `is.available() > 0` doesn't hold?

It depends on the body of the for-expression. For example, if it loads the lines of the file into a `Seq[String]`, it would return `Seq()`. If it counts the number of lines in the file, it would return `0` (if the body returns `Int`) or `None` (`Option[Int]`).

Guards, or filters, only make sense when they operate on a collection (`Option` can be considered a kind of collection whose maximum size is 1). Since `ForComprehensible` is just a syntactic trick to enable a loaner-function to be in for-generators, I conclude for now that we should stick to for-body if we want to check some conditions for acquiring resources.